# Image zoom + Modal?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using Cloud Zoom for image zoom:

http://www.professorcloud.com/mainsite/cloud-zoom-integration.htm

And I just saw SimpleModal, a Modal js script:

http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

I would like to integrate them both, to show the zoomed image in the modal

This is the website i'm developing:

http://criatweb.com.br/gigbr/light/

And this is the original, in flash:

http://gigbrasil.com.br

Take a look at the zoom tool of both and you'll get the picture.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these jQuery plugins: http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/pan

Comment: thanks for reply, but this isn't exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: Then you might be better of writing your own, if you can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Through a lot of trial and error, I was able to get this to work on a portfolio site.

On a Wordpress site, I set up both scripts. I used Cloud Zoom on an image in a post and called the post with SimpleModal. The modal window was stripping Cloud Zoom's formatting, but I got it to work by loading the Cloud Zoom script in ajax-handler.php in addition to header.php.

I am doubtful it is best practice to load the Cloud Zoom script twice, but it's what I could do based on my knowledge, without writing new script.